# MongoDB: How to aggregate $arrayElemAt in random postion instead of last and first?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am finding a solution to get ONE random value in a nested array in MongoDB.

My json:

```
{
  "name": "My name",
  "pictures": [
     "Pic1",
     "Pic2",
     "Pic3",
     "Pic4",
     "Pic5"
  ],
}
```

I ve read the Documentation about the [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) in Aggregation Pipeline Operators:

The available syntax is just:

`{ $arrayElemAt: [ <array>, <idx> ] }`

The `<idx>` expression can be set with first and last.

How can I get a random value in array?

My expected result:

```
{
  "name": "My name",
  "pictures": "Pic3", // This must be random
}
```

Comment: Do you need a random element for each document in an aggregation do you have only one document with the `pictures` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `mongo` shell native method [_rand()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rand/index.html) you can get a random position (and find a random picture using it):

```
db.test.aggregate( [
  {
      $addFields: {
          pictures: {
              $arrayElemAt: [ 
                   "$pictures",
                   { $floor: { $multiply: [ _rand(), { $floor: { $size: "$pictures" } } ] } }
               ]
          }
      }
  }
] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution with [$$NOW](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.NOW) variable (MongoDb `v4.2`):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      pictires: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$pictures",
          {
            $mod: [
              {
                $toLong: "$$NOW"
              },
              {
                $size: "$pictures"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EtBk1d8QvDk)